# How browsers are distinguishing between refresh and tab/browser close? [2020]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[Year 2020]. If i browse through the stackoverflow i could find a lot of questions regarding this, basically how we can identify these events.
**If i listen to *beforeunload* event, i basically want to know what will happen next for a new navigation, a tab close or a reload?** Many of the offered answers are very old or depricated.

> eg: performance.navigation.type

I still couldn't find a proper solution for this. If i refer back into those questions i could find many opinions not a working solution for it in 2020 because of the deprication. And when i console few values, surprisingly it returns "reload" for both refresh and close-tab events.

> ```
> eg: event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type === 1
>
> eg: performance.getEntriesByType('navigation').filter(item => item.type === 'reload').length
> ```

for both reload and tab/browser --close

However, one of my observation is, the BROWSER never misses it. It'll always render LEAVE_PAGE_ALERT for closing and RELOAD_PAGE_ALERT for refresh/reloading. So, there should be a way.

[image]

[image]

currently i'm handling Crtl+R, F5 etc. but i don't think that's the proper way to do so.

```
componentDidMount() {
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const key = event.which || event.keyCode;

  switch (key) {
    case 116: return this.registerableKeyEvent(true, 'isF5Down');
    case 17: return this.registerableKeyEvent(true, 'isRDown');
    case 82: return this.registerableKeyEvent(true, 'isCtrlDown');
    default: break;
  }
});
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
     //  if (tab/browser close) {...do stuff}
     //  if (refresh/reload) {...do stuff}

     if (!this.isF5Down && !this.isRDown && !this.isCtrlDown) {
      ...doing stuff
      event.returnValue = '';

      return '';
    }
   }
}
```

***So, my question is, how browsers distinguishing b/w these events? Maybe in such a way i can solve my problem.***

Comment: what you trying to do? - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#unloading-documents

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, my objective is in fact complicated, but i solved those problems(async call to invalidate and httpOnly token on tab/browser close(complicated because browser will block all async calls when the alert is open and in my application, timeout will mak the call as cancelled)). so it is working for regardless of refresh/close. but i should distinguish b/w them and should call it accordingly.

Comment: I guess one way would be to store a timestamp when the page exits. When the page loads, check how long ago that was and make a guess. Another way might be to store a session cookie. Afaik, those only appear in the context of the tab in which they were created and are automatically deleted if the tab is closed.

Comment: @Ouroborus, how exactly can i guess? sessionStorage is not working for me.

Comment: You need to know this for when the page is unloading? The solution you mentioned (`performance.navigation.type`, or its newer version `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type`)  tells you how the current page has been loaded, not how the next onewill be, nor what did trigger the *unload* event.

Comment: @Kaiido, all my intentions at this point is i shouldn't render the alert nor call the logout api on refresh but for tab/browser close. what i was able to achieve so far is to skip logging out and rendering alert for refresh page(only for F5/Crtl+R). But it is still happening for window.location.reload() calls(i cannot remove as they are old code and necessary for some modules) eg: when i open a different module, or downloading a pdf. SO WHAT I WAS THINKING, INSTEAD OF HANDLING MANY REFRESH/RELOAD, HANDLE ONLY LEAVE_PAGE(CLOSE TAB/BROWSER).

Comment: @Kaiido, if i can identify somehow closing tab/browser, i can call my api and logout properly and clear localStorage and sessionStorage, which'd be the whole point behind this question.

Comment: Alright, so I think we can start seeing clearer in your question. Basically: *You need to know in the *beforeunload* event what will happen next between a new navigation, a tab close or a reload. You did find a way to know how the current page has been loaded, but it's not what you need.* Do you think you can [edit] your question to reflect these points? Don't be afraid of editing it all, and to also include a bit of back story like more info about this API and the system you need to logout from.

Comment: guys, no way to identify?